# why isn't $P(A,B) = P(A\mid B) P(B\mid A)$?

Tags: probability

One of the rules of conditional probability is:

$$P(A,B) = P(A) P(B\mid A)$$

I was just wondering, since the left hand side is the joint probability (that $A$ and $B$ occur together), why when you break it out on the right hand side don't you have the following terms? Why isn't the following equation the correct one?

$$P(A,B) = P(A\mid B) P(B\mid A)$$

My intuition is that when we are talking about $P(A,B)$ we are describing a situation where $A$ has to be with $B$, **and** $B$ has to be with $A$. So why when we break it out into two terms, don't both terms reflect that constraint? Why doesn't the term for $A$ reflect the condition that it has to be found with $B$, **and** the term for $B$ reflect the condition that it has to be found with $A$?

Is the problem that it would be redundant? Or is there some other problem? I am really looking for a correct intuition to correct my apparently faulty intuition.

Comment: MathJax works in the title, don't you know?

Comment: Did not know that, thanks.

Comment: Although frankly it looks almost the same in that context ;)

Comment: I guess $A,B$ is your own special notation for the intersection $A\cap B$?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to answer your question if you would tell us ***why*** you think $P(A,B)$ should eaual $P(A|B)P(B|A)$? Because it really looks pretty random.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Your second equation just isn't true. We don't get to choose what the rule for conditional probability is, the universe gives it to us. Are you saying that you would have expected the answer to be the second one? If so, why?

Comment: What if $A=B$? Do you think that $P(A,A)=P(A|A)P(A|A)$? Isn't that the same as saying $P(A)=1$?

Comment: @bof yes by `A,B` I meant the intersection i.e. A AND B. I was copying this notation from my computer science lecture on Coursera, didn't know that it isn't widely recognized.

Comment: Sorry folks, I thought the "why" of my question was clear, but I guess not. I have edited it to hopefully be much clearer about what I am asking. I know the second equation is wrong, and that the universe gives us the rules - I am asking for intuition as to *why* it is wrong and to why the intuition I'm providing is incorrect.

Comment: I think your question is fine. As my answer points out, the equation you want is equivalent to independence. So you should probably think carefully about where in your intuition you are using that assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P(A|B) = P(A,B) / P(B)$.

So $P(A|B) P(B|A) = \dfrac{P(A,B)^2}{P(A)P(B)}$.

If this was equal to $P(A,B)$, (assuming none of the events are zero probability, etc.) we would have $P(A)P(B) = P(A,B)$. This is exactly the condition that $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

But not all events are independent.

So, if your intution leads you to this formula, somewhere you are assuming independence. I'd recommend working with some concrete examples, such as events if coin tosses, and compute them out thoroughly to figure the issue out.